# Возврат к предыдущему коммиту

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

На проекте случайно запушил смердженный коммит в основную дев ветку. В итоге на проекте прибавилось 900 не очень нужных строк :). 
Откатили через реверт, но тем самым затерли нужные коммиты. 
Решили откатиться до последнего нужного коммита через резет и хард пуш. 
Всё стало окей, на стенде появилась нужная версия приложения, при локальном запуске из этой дев ветки тоже все ок. 
Проблема проявилась в попытке **сделать пул в другие рабочие ветки**, все равно подтягивает версию, которая была удалена резетом и переписана форс пушем.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

В git log --graph HEAD нужный коммит, на который откатывались:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите `git log --graph`.

Comment: @TotalPusher залил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: что-то у меня очень много вопросов. это bare репозиторий? `все равно подтягивает версию` - имеется в виду, что в истории этот коммит есть? или что-то другое? на этом графе он есть? `Откатили через реверт, но тем самым затерли нужные коммиты.` как так то, не понимаю, реверт отменяет один конкретный коммит, вы что делали несколько ревертов хаотично? `при локальном запуске из этой дев ветки тоже все ок` - что за "локально"? на своей  машинке, где делались эти попытки исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы.

1) Если Вы не успели запулить в свою рабочую ветку удаленные данные, то стоит просто подождать апдейта на сервере.

2) Если же Вы подгружали в период возникновения проблемы ненужные данные на локальную машину или же запушили их в свою рабочую ветку, то это значит, что "локальная копия или копия рабочей ветки обогнала запуленную ветку на сервере". 
Необходимо:

Откатить Вашу рабочую ветку до последнего коммита, сделанного до злополучного пулла. 
Затем запушить разницу. 
И пулить актуальную версию с основной дев ветки.

```
git log --graph
git reset —hard [(то, что у Вас справа от commit )]
git commit
git push -f [branch]
git pull origin [dev branch]
```

P.S.:
Если уж совсем все плохо, то можно удалить ветку и залить заново с чистого листа :)